# Mongo-getting specific record from result

Tags: mongodb

I am new to Mongo. I have following query

> > db.getCollection('Market').find({"Id"
> >     : "52",
> >         "object" : "Slice" })

which gives me following results

```
"counter" : "ZZZ",
    "Id" : "2531",
    "Id2" : "4294ce01b97",
    "Index" : 5,
    "@Name" : "Price"
},
"Versions" : [ 
    {
        "value" : NumberDecimal("56.52"),
        "version" : NumberLong(1346)
    }, 
    {
         "value" : NumberDecimal("97.52"),
        "version" : NumberLong(1780)
    }, 
    {
        "value" : NumberDecimal("57.52"),
        "version" : NumberLong(13921)
    }
]
```

I need to extract **"value" : NumberDecimal("57.52"),** from above results.

I tried following

```
def value = (results.get("Versions") as ArrayList<Document>).last().getString("value")
```

However, this gives me error.

Comment: which version of mongodb is it?

Comment: can you elaborate your question? are you trying to find or update?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below query. 
It will return only one element from versions which match to your criteria.

EX :

```
db.getCollection('versions').find(
    { 'Versions.version': 13921},
    { 'Versions.$': 1 }
)
```

**NOTE : Change your collection name accordingly.**

Comment: Versions is not a collection.  That is the result of another collection query, now I want to filter version from Versions from that result which is in def results above

Comment: can you provide complete document.

Comment: sorry for telling that yet i could not understand your exact requirement. Can you provide me sample complete document and result what you expect. it will hep me to understand your requirement. also sample code you wrote